# SQL output multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get more values in a column and I'm testing it in phpMyAdmin:

I have a table `Nieuws` that contains in this case `ID` and a `Title`.

Table Nieuws
[image]

I have a table called `Nieuws_tags` where I give multiple tags to a item in column `Nieuws`.

table Nieuws_tags

[image]

The final column is called `Tags` that contains `ID` and `Beschrijving`

Table Tags

[image]

Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT * FROM (`Nieuws`) JOIN `Tags` ON `Tags`.`ID` = `Nieuws`.`ID` 
WHERE `Tags`.`ID` = 1
```

[image]

```
1 | Titel 1 | 1 | QBNL
```

Right now I only get one value back `QBNL`, but I gave it two values QBNL and QBBC. I'm pretty sure that my code is wrong but hopefully someone can help me.

EDIT: What I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bring in junction table `Nieuws_tags` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Nieuws`
INNER JOIN `Nieuws_tags` ON `Nieuws_tags`.`ID-Nieuws` = `Nieuws`.`ID` 
INNER JOIN `Tags` ON `Tags`.`ID` = `Nieuws_tags`.`ID-tags` 
WHERE `Tags`.`ID` = 1
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. Right now I'm getting a error: #1054 unknown column 'Nieuws.ID-tags' in on clause.

Comment: @ThijsvanRijn : sorry - should be `Nieuws_tags.ID-tags`

Comment: Is it correct that I still get one value back? Only QBNL and not QBNL and QBBC. I'm so sorry this is al new for me.

Comment: @ThijsvanRijn : do you want to filter by tag, or by news ?

Comment: In your data there is only one news that has tag `1`, hence you get a single record with the current query. However there are two tags that relate to news `1`, so if you change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE Nieuws.ID = 1` you will get rwo records.

Comment: @GMG you're right. Now I got two records. Is it possible to get the tags like 1,2,3,4 or only in different records? Thanks you very much

Comment: @ThijsvanRijn : not sure that I understand your question. You can filter on multiple tags with `Tags.ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`, or just remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GMG I'm sorry it's hard to explain in english. I added a extra picture in my post.

Comment: @ThijsvanRijn : that changes the query... You would need to use aggregation and `GROUP_CONCAT()`. If these hints are not enough, you might want to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the query if you need all the entries from tags.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Nieuws t1
INNER JOIN Nieuws_tags t2 ON t2.ID-Nieuws = t1.ID 
INNER JOIN Tags t3 ON t3.ID = t2.ID-tags 
WHERE t3.ID-Nieuws = 1
```